# Extract columns with same names from multiple data frames [R]

Tags: r

I am dealing with about 10 data frames that have the same column names, but different number of rows.  I would like to create a list of all columns with the same names.

So, say i have 2 data frames with the same names.

```
a<-seq(0,20,1)
b<-seq(20,40,1)
c<-seq(10,30,1)

df.abc.1<-data.frame(a,b,c)

a<-seq(20,50,1)
b<-seq(10,40,1)
c<-seq(30,60,1)

df.abc.2<-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I know i can create a list from this data such as,

```
list(df.abc.1$a, df.abc.2$a)
```

but i don't want to type out my long data frame names and column names.

I was hoping to do something like this,

```
list(c(df.abc.1, df.abc.2)$a)
```

But, it returns a list of df.abc.1$a

Perhaps there could be a way to use the grep function across multiple data.frames?
Perhaps a loop could accomplish this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it's any better, but maybe

```
lapply(list(df.abc.1, df.abc.2), function(x) x$a)
```

For more than one column

```
lapply(list(df.abc.1, df.abc.2), function(x) x[, c("a","b")])
```

Comment: Great!  This might be a long shot, but, i know within ls() i can specify a pattern (pattern="df") to list the names of my data.frames. But, i cannot figure out how to use this to specify the objects within the list function.

Comment: Try `ls.str(pattern= "df") `

Comment: Almost, I guess i am just being lazy, and want R to do it all.  When i do `a<-ls(pattern="df")` it gives me `"df.abc.1" "df.abc.2"` but what i really want is `df.abc.1, df.abc.2` i then want to input a into the list function you provided. Thank you for the great input.

Comment: May be you can write: lapply(lapply(ls(pattern="df"),get),`[`,"a") #extracting "column a".

Comment: ^  Genius!!  Works perfectly!  This is how is used it in my code, `lapply(lapply(ls(pattern="scp"), get),  function(x) x$NMDA.max)`