# Make a list from ls(pattern="") [R]

Tags: r, list

The `ls(pattern="")` function is very useful for me, since my list of objects seem to keep growing and growing. I am curious if this feature can be more useful.

For example, let's say i have 4 objects,

```
a.c<-1
b.c<-2
c.c<-3
d.c<-4
```

Now i use the useful `ls(pattern="")` function

```
ls(pattern=".c")
```

Now i try to make a list

```
list(ls(patter=".c"))
```

But it doesn't give me anything useful( `"a.c" "b.c" "c.c" "d.c"` ).  I want either of these two outputs

```
1,2,3,4
```

OR

```
a.c, b.c, c.c, d.c
```

Comment: (1) A very large number of (related) objects in your workspace is often a sign that they shouldn't really be separate objects, (2) Look into `mget` for your immediate problem.

Comment: I am all ears for how i could manage my objects.  I have 9 experiments with different number of cells in each experiment (anywhere between 200-800 cells).  I used r to compile 4 different data.frames for each experiment.  What do i do now?

Comment: You could use a single nested list. Store everything in that list. Then you can simply traverse the list and use tools like lapply, rather than constantly grabbing things from the workspace.

Comment: That sounds great.  Could you please point me in the right direction on this?  Still new to big data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1) The `.` in `".c"` gets ignored, you need to "escape" it:

```
ls(pattern="\\.c")
```

Otherwise it will return all objects with `c` regardless of having a period.

2) `ls` returns names of objects as character. To get the value of an object based on its name you need the function `get`:

```
lapply(ls(pattern="\\.c"), get)
```

3)  As joran mentioned in the comments, it's much better to keep objects associated with each other in lists:

```
List.c = list(a.c=1, b.c=2, c.c=3, d.c=4)
```

Comment: Awesome.  I would up vote, but i am new...  

This is how i used it!  (See this page for more bckground[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195109/extract-columns-with-same-names-from-multiple-data-frames-r/24196285#24196285]

 `lapply(lapply(ls(pattern="scp"), get),  function(x) x$NMDA.max)`

Comment: this is good to know! but as usual i was able on second glance to `lapply` creating the variables I wanted to find by `pattern`, so point 3) can't be emphasized enough.