# Select seperate objects in R and bind them to one dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, object, select, rbind

I was wondering how to select multiple objects in R and save them to a dataframe.
So let's say `ls()`gives me following objects:

```
ls()
 [1] "[.avector"             "a-32"                  "a-33"                 
 [4] "a_32"                  "a_33"                  "a_34"                 
 [7] "a_35"                  "a_36"                  "a_37"                 
[10] "a_38"                  "a_39"                  "a_40"                 
[13] "a_41"                  "a_42"                  "a_43"
```

how do connect ls[2:15] to one dataframe?

Thanks so much in advance!

## Edit:

Following your advice I used this code:

```
list<- mget(ls()[2:15])
df<- do.call(rbind, list)
```

asking for the class R tells me that df is a matrix.

so, I converted df to a dataframe yielding this:

```
df<- data.frame(df)
df

data.frame(df)
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21
a-32 NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA  NA   1   1  NA   6   2  NA  NA  NA   6  NA  NA
a-33 NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA  NA   1   3  NA   6   4  NA  NA  NA   6  NA  NA
a_32 NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA  NA   1   1  NA   6   2  NA  NA  NA   6  NA  NA
a_33 NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA  NA   1   3  NA   6   4  NA  NA  NA   6  NA  NA
a_34 NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA  NA   1   1  NA   4   1  NA  NA  NA   1  NA  NA
a_35 NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA  NA   1   1  NA   6   2  NA  NA  NA   6  NA  NA
a_36 NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA  NA   1   2  NA   6   4  NA  NA  NA   6  NA  NA
a_37 NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA  NA   4   2  NA   6   3  NA  NA  NA   4  NA  NA
a_38 NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA  NA   4   3  NA   6   3  NA  NA  NA   4  NA  N
.....
```

So if I see it correctly, R put my objects as rows. Can I bind them to colums?

## Edit 2:

I used cbind() and it worked out. Thank you so, so much for your help!

Comment: Try `do.call("rbind",mget(ls()[2:15]))` but it kind of depends on what all those objects really are

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387419/how-to-rbind-all-the-data-frames-in-your-working-environment

Comment: Also note [the `pattern` argument in `ls`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210327/make-a-list-from-lspattern-r).

Comment: Are each of those objects vectors?

Comment: Yup, class is numeric. They have many NAs.

Comment: Or grab objects from your environment based on a certain `class`, e.g.: [Use ls() or objects() to get objects of class data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796508/use-ls-or-objects-to-get-objects-of-class-data-frame).

Comment: I'm glad you figured somethingout, but if you solved your one question, then you should add that as an answer below. Do not edit your question to include an answer. That's not how Stack Overflow is meant to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
List <- mget(ls()[2:15])
df <- do.call(rbind,List)
```

Comment: Thanks! I posted an edit trying your code and it did not quite work out

Comment: Try `df <- do.call(cbind,List)` @a.henrietty Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 2):

The names of your objects have the same pattern, so it's more general to set the `pattern` argument in `ls()` to match objects. In addition, you can use `cbind.data.frame()` to bind several vectors by column.

```
cbind.data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "^a")))
```